# How does one find $\mathbf{P}(X<2\mu-\alpha)$ in terms of $\mathbf{P}(X<\alpha)$, given that $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A student of mine encountered the following question:

> Let $X$ be normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Suppose we're given a real number $\alpha > \mu$. Find $\mathbf{P}(X<2\mu-\alpha)$ in terms of $\mathbf{P}(X<\alpha)$.

Since $\alpha>\mu$, we deduce $0>\mu-\alpha$ by subtracting $\alpha$ from both sides. So $\mu > 2\mu-\alpha$ by adding $\mu$. This tells us that $$\mathbf{P}(X<\mu)>\mathbf{P}(X<2\mu-\alpha).$$ So the value of $\mathbf{P}(X<2\mu-\alpha)$ is at most $1/2$. Beyond this, I'm really not sure what we can say.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: You can use symmetry of the Gaussian about the mean $\mu$, and relate $P[X>\mu + c]$ and $P[X<\mu - c]$ for general constants $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\beta = (\mu -\alpha)$.  Then, since for a Gaussian we have

$$P( X < \mu + \beta) = 1 - P( X < \mu - \beta)$$ we have 
$$P( X < \mu + (\mu -\alpha)) = 1 - P( X < \mu - (\mu -\alpha))$$ or
$$P( X < 2\mu - \alpha) = 1 - P( X < \alpha)$$

I see that Michael's hint is pointing to this too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess another way of thinking about it is that if $X$ is a symmetrically distributed random variable with mean $\mu$, then $X$ has the same distribution as $2\mu-X$. Hence we can argue as follows:

$\mathbf{P}( X < 2\mu - \alpha) = \mathbf{P}( 2\mu-X < 2\mu - \alpha) = \mathbf{P}(-X<-\alpha) = \mathbf{P}(X>\alpha) = 1-\mathbf{P}(X<\alpha)$

This agrees with Mathemagical's answer.